# Irrigation valve solenoid sputters then closes

Tags: irrigation

When I trigger the valve through the irrigation controller, I get a small water trickle, then nothing. If I quarter turn the solenoid or use the bleed valve, I get a full flow of water.  Here's my irrigation setup (see picture):

- Hunter Node 400
- 1" Hunter irrigation valve
- DC Solenoid

Other relevant information:

- I have a 2nd irrigation valve on the same manifold, with the same issue as the first one.
- I have an 3rd irrigation valve situated 60'/20m away and about 6'/2m higher that works fine.
- If I close the water line, open the valve with the controller, then re-open the main, the water flows.

How do I get this to work?

[image: Irrigation setup]

Comment: Are these all new components?  What is your psi?  When you activate the valve do you watch it turn, does it turn the same amount as manually turning it?

Comment: All new components. Not sure about the psi. The valve does not turn when triggered by the controller, all the action happens in the solenoid.

Comment: How is the Node's power supply?  Does it have a battery or is it powered by 24V from somewhere upstream?  I've had issues with those controllers when battery powered - a battery at slightly-below full charge is more than enough to run the electronics (and light up the battery indicator all the way), but isn't enough to move the solenoid all the way.

Comment: It’s 9v battery operated, I’ll try and swap with a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was flow - the flow control screw was open, but not enough for proper operation. I unscrewed the central screw (see picture) and things starting working as designed. [image: highlight of central flow control screw on irrigation valve.]

Answer (score 4):

Open the 4 screws in the corners after you shutdown the water.

Activate the solenoid and observe the up/down movement.

It is spring loaded so it will jump out if you do not prevent it.

The assumption here the solenoid does not go up (to open) the water flow.

Assuming you have enough power to operate it, then it could be bad solenoid.

The manual operation does not uses same channel as the solenoid. Check the small hole under the solenoid for blockage.